# Using SWITCH and comparison operators to find total time in work hours

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to create a google sheet for the amount of time I work and how much is docked from my pay when I take breaks. I'm using the switch statement since the employer has set a fixed amount of time where we have to take our breaks.

- If a shift is 7 or more hours, we get a 30 minute break
- If a shift is between 4 and 7 hours, we get a 15 minute break
- If a shift is less than 4 hours, we get 5 minutes.

This is the formula I have come up with:

```
=SWITCH(E3="yes", D3 >= TIME(7,0,0), D3-TIME(0,30,0),                  TIME(7,0,0)>D3>=TIME(4,0,0), D3-TIME(0,15,0), D3<TIME(4,0,0), D3-TIME(0,5,0),D3)
```

Here are examples of my data:
[image]

[image]

If I type no in column E, the value in column F should be the same as D. But I get messed up numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `If a shift is less than 4 hours, we get 5 minutes.` - this kinda means that you will always have "yes" in E column... just saying...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. My understanding is the breaks are optional but if we do decide to take one we won't be paid for that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(E2="yes", IF(D2>=TIMEVALUE("7:00:00"), D2-TIMEVALUE("0:30:00"),
              IF(D2>=TIMEVALUE("4:00:00"), D2-TIMEVALUE("0:10:00"),
              IF(D2< TIMEVALUE("4:00:00"), D2-TIMEVALUE("0:05:00"), ))), D2)
```

[image]

Comment: I was considering that my formula was wonky because of how I converted time. Is this the reason you used timevalue instead of time? I also see that you didn't include the x hours between 4 and 7. Would your nested if statements be similar to how switch works?

Comment: `IF` can handle nested priority logic so if the first row gets to evaluate as `FALSE` it will jump on the evaluation of 2nd row - that's why there is no need to state the time between 4-7